# Show that $F|_{\phi} :\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[t]$ is isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Let $V = \{(\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3):\alpha\in\mathbb R\}$. Show that if $\Phi :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is the polynomial function $\Phi(\alpha)=(\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3)$ (which gives the morphism $\phi :\mathbb{R}\rightarrow V$ ), then
$$F|_{\phi} :\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[t],  f(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z})\mapsto f(t,t^2,t^3)$$
is a ring isomorphism, where $I = \langle y-x^2,z-x^3\rangle$.

From previous steps of this problem, I have shown that $I=\mathscr{I}(V)$ (the vanishing ideal of $V$).
I know that I have to show that the kernel of this map is $I$ and the Image is $\mathbb{R}[t]$ so I can use the first isomorphism theorem but I am so confused that I'm unable to proceed.

Comment: Your map doesn't make sense. The image $(t,t^2,t^3)$ is a point of $\mathbb{R}^3$, not a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[t]$ as it should be.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley just edited, thanks.

Comment: Ok great, that's the right one. Now ask can it be true that $F|_\phi$ is an isomorphism if its kernel is $I$?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Isn't it sufficient to show that the Kernel of that map is $I$ and the Image is $\mathbb{R}[t]$ from the 1st isomorphism theorem? That was my main idea to be honest

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Could you write explicitly what is your thought? I dont have any idea of how to construct the inverse.

Comment: @KCd Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field, and let $I$ be the ideal generated by $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$ in $A:=k[x,y,z]$. There is a map of algebras $\phi:k[x,y,z]\to k[t]$ such that $\phi(x)=t$, $\phi(y)=t^2$, $\phi(z)=t^3$. This map vanishes on the generators of the ideal $I$, so it induces a map $\bar\phi:A/I\to k[t]$ such that $\bar\phi(x+I)=t$, $\bar\phi(y+I)=t^2$ and $\bar\phi(z+I)=t^3$.

On the other hand, there is obviously a map of algebras $\psi:k[t]\to A/I$ such that $\psi(t)=x+I$.

I claim that $\bar\phi$ and $\psi$ are mutually inverse morphisms abnd, in particular, isomorphisms.

- To check that $\bar\phi\circ\psi$ is the identity of $k[t]$ it is enough to check that its value on $t$ is $t$, and that is easy: $$\bar\phi(\psi(t)))=\bar\phi(x+I)=t.$$
- Similarly, to check that $\psi\circ\bar\phi$ is the identity of $A/I$ it is enough to check that it maps each of the three classes $x+I$, $y+I$ and $z+I$ to themselves:
  \begin{align}
  \psi(\bar\phi(x+I)) &= \psi(t) = x+I, \\
  \psi(\bar\phi(y+I)) &= \psi(t^2+I) = x^2+I = y+I, \\
  \psi(\bar\phi(z+I)) &= \psi(t^3+I) = x^3+I = z+I, 
  \end{align}
  since $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$ are in $I$.

This proves what we want.

Comment: This is really useful. Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. If you want to use the first isomorphism theorem to conclude that $R/I\cong S$ for rings $R,S$ then you can do this immediately if you can get a surjective homomorphism $f:R\to S$ with kernel equal to $I$. Note that the map you need is not from the quotient ring $R/I$ to $S$, but it is from $R$ itself to $S$.

In your case, $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$, $S=\mathbb{R}[t]$. Hopefully you can get it from here, but reply if you try and still need more help.

Comment: Is it correct if I take $f$ to be the mapping from $R$ to $S$ with $f(x)=t$,$f(y)=t^2$ and $f(z)=t^3$?

Comment: Yes! Can you show that this map is surjective and that its kernel is $I$?

Comment: Yes, this mapping is obviously onto $\mathbb{R}[t]$ by construction. Then, the Ker(f)=I by previous steps that this poblem had to be shown.

Comment: The problem is that I need to show that $F|_{\phi}$ is isomorphism and not that the two rings are isomorphic.

Comment: Your $F|_\phi$ is exactly the isomorphism that is described in the first isomorphism theorem!